# The only subgroup $S$ of $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ with $|\operatorname{Aut}(S)|=2$ is $S\simeq\mathbb{Z}\times \{a\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

An exercise from a lecture: find example of subgroup $S$ of $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ with only two automorphisms, i.e., $|\operatorname{Aut}(S)|=2$.

Any mistakes?

The claim is that the only possibility is $S\simeq\mathbb{Z}\times \{a\}$, where $a$ is some rational, say $a=0$.

Assume there is such an $S$ with two generators $g_{1},g_{2}$. Since it has only two automorphisms, those will just be $Id_{S}$ and $-Id_{S}$. But then we can construct a third one:

$g_{1}\to -g_{1}$ and $g_{2}\to g_{2}$

So it must have one generator and thus $S\simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your proof is correct; every such subgroup is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.  However, not all of them are of the form $\mathbb{Z} \times \{a\}$.  What about the subgroup generated by $(1,1)$, for instance?

Comment: I changed it to isomorphic